# Saving a figure with subplots without padding white margins

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The following code removes the padding around a bunch of subplots in MATLAB. I found it in a comment from [here](http://tipstrickshowtos.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/how-to-get-rid-of-white-margin-in.html).

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;
h=figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,sin(x))
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,cos(x))

a = findall(h,'type','axes');
for i=1:length(a)
    ti = get(a(i),'TightInset');
    op = get(a(i),'OuterPosition');
    set(a(i),'Position',[op(1)+ti(1) op(2)+ti(2) op(3)-ti(3)-ti(1) op(4)-ti(4)-ti(2)]);
end
```

I don't know what the rest of his code is doing. But, this much of code does the job (thought not very accurate).

Now, my problem is that I don't wana remove the padding when showing since it gets ugly. I just want to remove the padding while saving with command `print` or `saveas`. Is there any way for that?

Comment: look into subplot_tight  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30884-controllable-tight-subplot/content/subplot_tight/subplot_tight.m

Comment: @bla, this link is for showing not saving. I want to show paddings but not saving them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a quick fix. It works, but isn't really elegant:

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;
h1 = figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,sin(x))
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,cos(x))

%% Save figure

x = -pi:.1:pi;
h2 = figure('visible','off');
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,sin(x))
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,cos(x))

a = findall(h2,'type','axes');
for i=1:length(a)
    ti = get(a(i),'TightInset');
    op = get(a(i),'OuterPosition');
    set(a(i),'Position',[op(1)+ti(1) op(2)+ti(2) op(3)-ti(3)-ti(1) op(4)-ti(4)-ti(2)]);
end
saveas(h2,'newout','fig')
```